# How to add FloatingActionButton on maps in xamarin.android

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, floating-action-button

I am trying to add custom button for locate me for the maps. I came to know we need to use FloatingActionButton, so I have created as following in my layout.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/header">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/mapToolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/maptype_arrays" />
    <fragment
        android.id="@+id/map"
        android:tag="maptag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:src="@drawable/locateme_icon"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But Im not getting button on the screen when run this. Is there anything to add along with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the FloatingActionButton displayed by changing Linear layout to Frame layout.